# How correctly get object by screenshot point coordinates in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make next:

- get screenshot from camera
- process it with python script and find some points
- for each point - find object that projected to this point

Screenshot getting code works well. Python script output has next view:

```
x=X1 y=Y1 ... \n
x=X2 y=Y2 ... \n
```

Where 0 <= X1 < screenshot width, 0 <= Y1 < screenshot height.

E.g. in debug mode I can see next image :[image: screenshot]

As you can see - part of points located on chairs/table projections.

And I need to get this chair/table objects (each object have attached `BoxCollider`).
I trying to get ray with `camera.ScreenPointToRay` and `Physics.Raycast`, but I have wrong output:

```
private void ApplyClassTextures()
{
    var screenshot = GetComponent<Screenshoter>().MakeScreenshot();
    Debug.Log(screenshot);
    var map = GetComponent<Scenemap>().MakeMap(screenshot);
    var objectContours = new Dictionary<GameObject, List<Scenemap.MapContour>>();
    var camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
    foreach (var item in map)
    {
        var ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(item.X, item.Y, 0.0f));
        var rayHit = new RaycastHit();
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out rayHit, raycastHitDistance))
        {
            var obj = rayHit.collider.gameObject;
            if (!objectContours.ContainsKey(obj))
            {
                Debug.Log(obj);
                objectContours.Add(obj, new List<Scenemap.MapContour>());
            }
            objectContours[obj].Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

And there I can see few floor/wall plane and one chair, but not other and table.

Comment: From the information you provide I can only guess: in your python script you are using OpenCV for whatever task. In OpenCVs coordinate system, the origin is in the top left corner, whereas the origin in unitys screen coordinate system is in the bottom left corner. Mayber you have to mirror your input points before using `ScreenPointToRay`?

Comment: Thanks, seems like I missed this detail.